# libevent: uninitialized structure pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, libevent

I have struct pointer in code

```
struct evkeyvalq *headers;
```

now I give call to a function which would fill some information in the structure.

```
evhttp_parse_query(uri, headers)
```

I get segmentation fault at this line. what would be the correct way to doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate some memory for your struct evkeyvalq. As your code is now, you pass an uninitialized pointer into evhttp_parse_query() , and there is no way for evhttp_parse_query() to operate properly.

Allocate the struct on the stack:

```
struct evkeyvalq headers;
evhttp_parse_query(uri, &headers);
```

Or use dynamically allocated memory:

```
struct evkeyvalq *headers = malloc(sizeof *headers);
if(headers != NULL) {
    evhttp_parse_query(uri, headers);
}
```